# Predict output using image and text variables as input

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification

I need to implement a solution where I will have an image and other text variables as temperature, humidity and precipitacion. I wish to preview the inflow as output based on these inputs.

I suspect that I'd need a CNN to classify the image and combine it with the other variables (precipitacion,temperature and humidity).

Does anyone here have a similiar problem that can share the source code with me?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what "preview the inflow" means.  I doubt that requests for source code are on-topic here.  Our purpose is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, in the form of question and answers.

Comment: Please find [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on/129632#129632)